# URL Parsing - routing or other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of migrating PHP code to ASP.NET MVC and previously for the register page I would store if the new user had accepted the rules and also was COPPA verified by redirecting from `/register` to `/register&readrules=1&coppa=1`. I would then just parse the @readrules and @coppa in the code.

What is the best way to do this in ASP.NET? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query string parameters instead:

```
/register?readrules=1&coppa=1
```

This is more standard and you do not need any parsing. Just define a view model to accomodate those values:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Readrules { get; set; }
    public int Coppa { get; set; }
}
```

and ten have your Register controller action take this view model as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Register(MyViewModel model)
{
    ... at this stage model.Readrules and model.Coppa will contain the values passed
        as query string parameters tat you could use here
}
```

The default model binder will automatically bind the values of the `readrules` and `coppa` query string parameters to the corresponding properties of the view model that your controller action takes.